# How to grab every n,n+1 th lines from a text file

Tags: linux, text, sed, line

I have a huge text file where i need to grab every n, n+1 th line in a separate file.

I came across sed command but that could help me grab every n th line only from a text file.
For example:

**

````
$ sed -n '0~4p' somefile**
**```**
Any suggestions on grabbing n+1th line at the same time?


**
````

$ sed -n '0~4p' somefile**
**```**

Comment: Can you add some sample input/output? For example, what should be the expected output for `seq 20` as input?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '4~4,+1p' file
```

This will print the 4th plus one lines starting at line 4.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible solution (guessing that this is the required output):

```bash
$ seq 20 | sed -n '0~4{N;p}'
4
5
8
9
12
13
16
17
```

As per [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Other-Commands) for the `N` command:

> Add a newline to the pattern space, then append the next line of input
> to the pattern space. If there is no more input then sed exits without
> processing any more commands. When -z is used, a zero byte (the ascii
> ‘NUL’ character) is added between the lines (instead of a new line).

If `20` should also be part of the output for the above input, you can use:

```bash
seq 20 | sed -n '0~4{p;n;p}'

# alternative solution if ~ address range isn't supported
seq 20 | sed -n '1b; n;n;p;n;p'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `~` option to `sed` is non-standard, but might be made to do what you want.  But it seems more natural to use `awk`:

```
 awk 'NR>1 && NR % n  < 2' n=5
```

(eg):

```
$ yes | nl | sed 20q |  awk 'NR>1 && NR % n  < 2' n=5
     5  y
     6  y
    10  y
    11  y
    15  y
    16  y
    20  y
```