# Delete first N char from a text file

Tags: linux, awk, text, sed

I have large data file with some data as :

```
01 01 00 2c 00 82 03 00 02 00 00 00 07 08 07 08   
07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08   
07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08   
07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08   
0f 08 08 08 0a 08 07 08 0f 08 08 08 08 08 08 08   
08 08 08 08 08 07 08 07 0a 07 07 07 0f 07 08 07   
08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 0a 07 07 07   
..
.....
```

I would like to delete every first n characters from every 6th row

I have found a command :

```
sed 's/^.\{,n\}//' file
```

But this command deletes first n chars from each row, which I do not want to happen.

Could someone suggest the right command?

Comment: [[tag:cmd]] is not available on [[tag:linux]]. Please [Edit] your question to clarify, and make sure you use only tags appropriate to your issue.

Comment: Please take a look at `man sed` and search for `~` or take a look at [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74222421/how-to-grab-every-n-n1-th-lines-from-a-text-file).

Comment: you've provided a sample input of 7 lines; please update the question to show the expected output for, say, deleting the first n=9 characters from every 3rd row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -v n=17 '(NR%6)==1 { print substr($0, n+1); next } 1' file
```

The condition uses modulo arithmetic on the line number `NR` to select every sixth line, starting from the first. The final `1` causes the other lines to be printed normally.

You haven't revealed the value of `n` so I guessed.

Comment: or `awk -v n=17 '(NR%6)==1 { $0=substr($0, n) } 1' file` so you aren't printing from 2 places.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to avoid rescanning the line but that would work too.

Comment: You're one off though. You're removing `n-1` characters. Changing to `...substr($0, n+1)...` would fix it.

Comment: @karakfa You're right, I meant to remark on that but skipped it because we don't know `n` anyway. But it's definitely clearer this way.

Comment: @triplee - ah, makes sense, then `awk -v n=17 '{print ( (NR%6)==1 ? substr($0, n) : $0 ) }' file` would avoid 2 separate output statements (only matters if you need to modify the output in future) but none of it matters much either way.

Answer (score 3):

GNU `sed` allows you to use [address](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Addresses.html) in form of

> first~step
>
> (...)matches every stepth line starting with line first(...)

therefore `1~6` does pertain to 1st, 7th, 13th and so on lines, `2~6` pertains to 2nd, 8th, 14th and so on lines, let `file.txt` content be

```
01 01 00 2c 00 82 03 00 02 00 00 00 07 08 07 08   
07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08   
07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08   
07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08   
0f 08 08 08 0a 08 07 08 0f 08 08 08 08 08 08 08   
08 08 08 08 08 07 08 07 0a 07 07 07 0f 07 08 07   
08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 0a 07 07 07   
..
.....
```

and n be equal to 5 then, you might do

```
sed '1~6 s/^.....//' file.txt
```

which gives output

```
 00 2c 00 82 03 00 02 00 00 00 07 08 07 08   
07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08   
07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08   
07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08   
0f 08 08 08 0a 08 07 08 0f 08 08 08 08 08 08 08   
08 08 08 08 08 07 08 07 0a 07 07 07 0f 07 08 07   
 08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 08 07 0a 07 07 07   
..
.....
```

*(tested GNU sed 4.7)*

Comment: In case someone wants to apply your code to another file: The line to be shortened must contain at least five characters.

Answer (score 0):

`gawk/nawk` solution. `mawk`s would need a slightly diff approach

```
for N in $(jot - 2 28 7); do 
  
    jot -b '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789' 8 |
```

> ```
> gawk -v FS='^.{'"$N"'}' 'BEGIN { _^=OFS=_ } NR%6!=_ || NF=NF' | gcat -n
> ```

```
  echo "${N}"
done
```

> 

```
     1  23456789012345678901234567890123456789
     2  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789
     3  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789
     4  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789
     5  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789
     6  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789
     7  23456789012345678901234567890123456789
     8  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789
2
     1  9012345678901234567890123456789
     2  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789
     3  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789
     4  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789
     5  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789
     6  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789
     7  9012345678901234567890123456789
     8  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789
9
     1  678901234567890123456789
     2  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789
     3  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789
     4  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789
     5  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789
     6  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789
     7  678901234567890123456789
     8  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789
16
     1  34567890123456789
     2  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789
     3  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789
     4  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789
     5  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789
     6  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789
     7  34567890123456789
     8  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789
23
```